# Getting FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass teardown error in appium

Tags: java, android, eclipse, automation, appium

I am getting ***CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass teardown and FAILED: testCal*** error in appium.How to resolve this? I ran my test using TestNG.Please find below for details:

```
package Appium;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileBrowserType;
import java.net.URL;

public class AppiumPOC {


        WebDriver driver;

        @BeforeClass
        public void Appium() throws MalformedURLException{

            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.2.2");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","4100a9102db72100");
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "WINDOWS");


            capabilities.setCapability("app", "chrome");
            WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);



          }

        @Test
        public void testCal()
        {
            driver.get("http://google.com");

        }

        @AfterClass
        public void teardown(){
            //close the app
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```

Please find below for the console message.I used my test using TestNg run method and tried in different platform still i m facing the same issue.

> ```
> [TestNG] Running:
>   C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-1668712669\testngcustomsuite.xml
> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass teardown
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at Appium.AppiumPOC.teardown(AppiumPOC.java:55)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
>   at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
>   at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
>   at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
>   at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeAfterClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:225)
>   at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:114)
>   at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
>   at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>   at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
>   at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
>   at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
>   at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
>   at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
>   at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
>
> FAILED: testCal
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at Appium.AppiumPOC.testCal(AppiumPOC.java:48)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
>   at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
>   at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
>   at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
>   at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
>   at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
>   at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
>   at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>   at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
>   at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
>   at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
>   at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
>   at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
>   at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
>
>
> ===============================================
>     Default test
>     Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
>     Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
> ===============================================
>
>
> ===============================================
> Default suite
> Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
> Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
> ===============================================
>
> [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@61064425: 18 ms
> [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@6a6824be: 89 ms
> [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@77556fd: 119 ms
> [TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 12 ms
> [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@2f333739: 28 ms
> [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@6ed3ef1: 19 ms
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. It works on my side now. Just remove the "WebDriver" from this line:

```
 driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me if I removed 'WebDriver' while creating object of new ChromeDriver

**[driver=new ChromeDriver();](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJEZa.png)**

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJEZa.png)